# Plotting the overlay using an exponential smoothing of a time-series using `lines()`

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

/* I don't want to use `HoltWinters` function in R and I have seen the [R code](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/HoltWinters.R) for holtwinters function but I really don't want to implement or copy the whole R code. mainly I want to write a code to have the same result as the answer we will receive by holtwinters */

I have the following code so far but I am not sure which function I should use for plotting the yearly average measurements of temperature for New Hampshire, from 1912 to 1971, and overlay an exponential smoothing of it using `lines()`

```
require(datasets)
data(nhtemp)
plot.ts(nhtemp)
lines(nhtemp, col="red") # gives the same plot as plot.ts(nhtemp)!!
```

I am not sure how to overlay an exponential smoothing of `nhtemp` using `lines()`
P.S.: I don't want to try any external packages like `forecast` or `stats` but I was just trying the following for some experiments:
I tried to follow the instructions mentioned in the following picture but I received this error:
[image]

```
> lines(nhtemp$fitted)
#Error in lines(nhtemp$fitted) : 
#  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'lines': #Error in nhtemp$fitted : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> HoltWinters(nhtemp)
#Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : 
#  time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

Comment: Isn't this post more related to Cross-Validated? I am not sure why it has been migrated or closed?!

Comment: This should go to CrossValidated and you need to rephrase the whole question. As the code you've tried implies that you are trying to run `HoltWinters()` function on some data set and getting an error, while actually what you wan to do is to write an exponential smoothing function on your own

Answer (score 1):

Since your data set is not seasonal (`Frequency = 1`), you should fit a non-seasonal Holt-Winters by specifying `gamma = F`.

Also, doing `lines(nhtemp$fitted)` (in your code) didn't make any sense, as you don't have fitted values in the original data.

So in order to reproduce the example in the book, you will have to do the folowing (which is basically just an exponential smoothing)

```
plot(nhtemp)
lines(HoltWinters(nhtemp, gamma=F)$fitted[,2], col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you David but I don't want to use any external packages and want to use already installed packages in RStudio. Any solution to that?

Comment: What external packages? I just ran your code with adding `gamma = F`. I didn't add any package

Comment: I know. I meant I don't want to use `HoltWinters`. Sorry if I was vague.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any other exponensial smoothing function in base R. You can run it from the `forecast` package too though if you like by `library(forecast); plot(nhtemp); lines(ses(nhtemp)$fitted, col = "red")`

Comment: Can you please take a look at the updated question? As I said I am supposed to write my own function. I am stuck where to start if I am not supposed to use any external packages like `stats` or `forecast`! Any hint is really appreciated! :)